# i18n in vue 3 with vite plugin for quasar

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, vue-i18n

I'm having troubles to use the vue-i18n in vue3 and quasar (no cli). There a following problems:

1. $t is not recognized and only works if used in html
2. quasar components are not localized.

Here is my main.js content:

```js
import './assets/main.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import { Quasar } from 'quasar'

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import './axios'

import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";


import '@quasar/extras/material-icons/material-icons.css'
import 'quasar/src/css/index.sass'


const i18n = createI18n({
    locale: 'de',
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    messages: loadLocaleMessages(),
    legacy: false,
    globalInjection: true
})

import en from './locales/en.json'
import de from './locales/de.json'

 function loadLocaleMessages() {
    const locales = [{en: en}, {de: de}]
    const messages = {}
    locales.forEach(locale => {
        const key = Object.keys(locale)
        messages[key] = locale[key]
    })
    return messages
}

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)
app.use(Quasar, {
    plugins: {}, 
})
app.use(i18n)

app.mount('#app')
```

and here is my sample component:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">

import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useRoute, useRouter, RouterLink } from 'vue-router'
import userService from '../services/users.service.js'

const username = ref('')
const password = ref('')

// following line is not working because of "Cannot find $t"
console.log('Testoutput', $t('username'))

const router = useRouter();

const login = async () => {
  var result = await userService.login(username.value, password.value)
  console.log(result)

  router.push({ name: 'home' })
}

</script>
```

```html
<template>

  <div class="q-pa-md row justify-center items-center" style="height: calc(100vh - 80px);">

        <q-card style="width: 400px" >
          <q-card-section>
            <q-form @submit="login" >
              <q-input
                filled
                v-model="username"
                :label="$t('username')"
                lazy-rules
                :rules="[(val: string) => !!val || 'Username is required']"
              />
              <q-input
                filled
                v-model="password"
                :label="$t('password')"
                lazy-rules
                
                :rules="[(val: string) => !!val || 'Password is required']"
                type="password"
              />
              <q-btn type="submit" :label="$t('login')" color="primary" />
            </q-form>
          </q-card-section>
        </q-card>
      </div>

</template>
```

Do you have any ideas?

Please ignore the following part. It is only necessary for posting my question, because it contains mainly code.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

Answer (score 0):

1. IIRC, $t is globalized, but in order to use it in code, you must first get that reference by using

   const {t} = useI18n();

Then you can use it as you do in the template:

```
const translated = t('myTranslationKey');
```

2. I use vue 3, vite, Quasar 2, vue-i18n 9, intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n

IIRC, you need to include the i18n in the Quasar boot (not cli):

in the Quasar options add:

```
{
...
boot: ['i18n']
}
```

to switch languages, i used this to start with https://lokalise.com/blog/vue-i18n/ and then adapted that to set the Quasar locale:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";
import Tr from "@/i18n/translation";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { useQuasar } from "quasar";
export default {
  setup() {
    const { t, locale } = useI18n();
    const $q = useQuasar();
    const router = useRouter();
    const switchLanguage = async (newLocale: string) => {
    // set the locale for i18n
    await Tr.switchLanguage(newLocale);
    // dynamically load the quasar module. Note that I used the i18n translation to transform/map the locale into a module name/path.
    const fn = "../i18n/quasar/" + t("locale.quasarLocale-" + newLocale) + ".mjs";
    const language = await import(/* @vite-ignore */ fn);
    // This is the business end: set the language for Quasar
    $q.lang.set(language.default);
    // optional: I use the locale in the url, so i rewrite the url with the new locale in it.          
    await router.replace({ params: { locale: newLocale } });          
    };
    return { t, locale, supportedLocales, switchLanguage };
  },
};
</script>
```

Note! I had to copy the .mjs files, found in the Quasar module folder in the node_modules/quasar/lang/* into a project folder (in my example i18n/quasar/) in order to get this to work.

I hope I got everything. It's some time ago I set this up, and I am not known for my memory, so YMMV.